# How would perform a piecewise equation with multiple variables in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to do the following piecewise function:

```
y(x,t) = {  0                   (t - 5) < 0 
         { (t - 5)*(t - x)      x < (t - 5) 
         { (t + x^2)            x >= (t - 5)
```

I don't seem to understand how to graph this function since x = 0:.5:10 and t = 0:.1:10. I know how to do this without the t but I get lost when the t is included and has different intervals compared to the x.

Thanks, Y_Y

Comment: I think you mean `y(x,t) = ...`

Comment: Your problem is how to write such a function, or how to plot it? If you want to plot it, look at the command meshgrid (help meshgrid includes an example)

Comment: I need to be able to do the equation. The thing is that Y is a 2-dimensional graph having t as a constant for each of its interval. x is the independent variable and y is the dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by the truth value usually works, and then you simply add the values together:

```
y = @(x,t)( (t-5).*(t-x).*(x<(t-5)) + (t+x.^2).*(x>=(t-5)) );
```

I can't test this right now as I don't have MATLAB on my laptop, but it should work the way you want it to.

---

Your real problem seems to be related to the fact that `x` and `t` are of different dimensions. This can be "fixed" using the [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) function, which creates two matrices for use in multi-dimensional functions:

```
[X, T] = meshgrid([1:.5:10], [0:.1:10]);
Z = y(X, T); % With y(x,t) as above
```

`Z` is now a matrix containing the values of `y` for different `x` and `t` accordingly. This can be plotted as a surface using `surf`:

```
surf(X, T, Z);
```

Comment: x and t must be in the same dimension if I do that.

Comment: Edited; use the `meshgrid` function to create suitable input matrices.