# Declare nonlinear constraint as anonymous function

Tags: matlab

How can I declare a nonlinear constraint in MATLAB as an anonymous function.  I don't have any inequality constrained, only one equality.

Comment: When you say "nonlinear", do you mean *piecewise*. If so, these other questions should help you: [How can I create a piecewise inline function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796072/how-can-i-create-a-piecewise-inline-function-in-matlab), [How would perform a piecewise equation with multiple variables in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383078/how-would-perform-a-piecewise-equation-with-multiple-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: I guess you want to use that constraint with fmincon but you should edit your question and explictly say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to create an anonymous functions that outputs two arguments. You can do that as follows:

```
@(x) deal(x^2, 0 )
```

is what you want. The inequality constraint is the first argument. If you want to have both then equality and inequality constraints it is just.

```
@(x) deal(x^2, x+1)
```